# Error while installing the Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, failed-installation

I am getting following error when installing Android Studio:

"the following sdk components were not installed: android support repository"

I am running Mac OS X El Capitan.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/bb2sk2

I tried it a couple of times over past couple of days thinking that it might be my internet connection issue. Also tried re-installing the Android studio.

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can open android studio, go to `Preferences`:

[image]

click on `Launch standalone SDK Manager`.

- Select `Android SDK Tools` and `Android SDK Platform-tools` and update.

[image]

- restart your SDK Manager. `Android Support Repository` will now be available under Extras.

[image]